# Generate Random 32 Bit Number in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js

What is the best way to generate a 32 bit random unsigned number in Node?  Here is what I tried:

```
var max32 = Math.pow(2, 32) - 1
var session = Math.floor(Math.random() * max32);
```

I need this for a unique id.

Comment: The biggest 16 bit number is 65535, so if you're getting 100,000 you've got some real issues.

Comment: @Pointy transcribed it wrong.

Comment: I often use `Math.random()*2**32|0` for `int32` and `Math.random()*2**32>>>0` for `uint32`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use [`crypto.randomBytes()`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_randombytes_size_callback) like:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
function randU32Sync() {
  return crypto.randomBytes(4).readUInt32BE(0, true);
}
// or
function randU32(cb) {
  return crypto.randomBytes(4, function(err, buf) {
    if (err) return cb(err);
    cb(null, buf.readUInt32BE(0, true));
  }
}
```

Comment: This sometimes generates numbers larger than `2147483651`, which is the max unsigned 32 bit integer I believe

Comment: @Shamoon The largest unsigned 32-bit integer value is 4294967295. The largest positive _signed_ 32-bit integer value is 2147483647. The solution I posted generates any unsigned 32-bit integer value, which is what was originally asked for.